# I keep getting errors in my react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, yarn-workspaces

I have been trying to install gh-packages for a while now. But I keep getting error. I have uninstalled and installed node.js globally, changed network but I still get these error.

Even after I uninstalled  and installed Node I was able to install React-router-dom packages, but when I tried installing gh-pages it throws an error.

Below is the error

$ npm install gh-pages --save-dev
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://toju-toby22.githuub.io/my-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND toju-toby22.githuub.io
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-20T22_50_58_984Z-debug-0.log

Comment: The domain `http://toju-toby22.githuub.io/my-app` looks incorrect (`uu`). Was that configured somewhere?

Comment: Matt I'm just noticing it now

Comment: Yes Matt in my package.json. Thank you it was the spelling. Its installed now @Matt